# I need to integrate python script along with libraries to spring-boot application

Tags: python, spring-boot, maven, spring-integration, executable-jar

I am developing a spring boot application, where it needs to call a python script with few arguments and get back the results from python. I need to develop the application as a single unit that is portable. I have an idea of using maven jpython/python integration (making jar file of python + libraries for python stuff). Is this possible? If it is how to do that? Or another way to do maven python integration?

Answer (score 0):

> it needs to call a python script with few arguments and get back the results from python

Not sure if you really are familiar with [Spring Integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration), but since you mention that tag, I'm going to share with you a scripting support in that project when Python language is one of those which you can use for such an integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#scripting

Here is also some sample project with scripting support: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/cafe-scripted